# Responsively position upper edge of a div at the centre point of a circle which is in another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 2 stacked divs: div1 contains an circle image, div2 contains some text. I'd like div2 to move upwards and always cover half of the circle, i.e. upper edge of div2 should be positioned at the centre point of the circle. Here is my code:

```css
.coverLower {
background: #e1ecf4;
margin-top: -235px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/03/Circle-withsegments.svg/1200px-Circle-withsegments.svg.png" style="width: 100%"></img>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 coverLower">
          text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I manually set `margin-top` to be a value to make it work in my browser with full screen, but problem is if I resize the screen to be narrower, the position is no longer correct. Guess manually setting this is wrong, how to make the position always correct responsively?

Comment: can we change the HTML?

Comment: @Aman Yes you can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can position the div absolutely like below:

```css
.coverLower {
  background: #e1ecf4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/03/Circle-withsegments.svg/1200px-Circle-withsegments.svg.png" style="width: 100%" />
      <div class="coverLower">
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        text text text text text text text text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```